# Button that loads values into jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, youtube

I am using Jquery youtube player plugin found here: http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/

The plugin allows you the specify a title for the youtube video you wish to play and the youtube video ID. Here is a snip it of the code:

```
var config =  {

            repeatPlaylist: 1,
            showTime: 1,
            height: 356,
            toolbar: 'play,prev,next,shuffle,repeat,mute', // comma separated list of toolbar buttons

            // Custom playlist
            playlist: {
                title: 'Random videos',
                videos: [
                    { id: 'youtube video id goes here', title: 'title goes here' },
                ]
            }

        };
```

I would like to create a button and assign the youtube id and video title. When pressed I would like those values to be used to load the youtube video using the jQuery plugin above **without refreshing the page**.

I have no clue how to do this. I have spent hours trying to figure it out without any luck. Any help would be greatly. appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="youtube-player"></div>         <!-- this element will be replaced -->

<button type="button" id="videoBtn1">video 1</button>
<button type="button" id="videoBtn2">video 2</button>
```

js:

```
function loadYouTube(id, title) {
    // your config with the parameters id and title
    var config =  {
        repeatPlaylist: 1,
        showTime: 1,
        height: 356,
        toolbar: 'play,prev,next,shuffle,repeat,mute',
        // Custom playlist
        playlist: {
            title: 'Random videos',
            videos: [{ id: id, title: title }]
        }
    };
    // replace the html element with an empty you-tube plugin html code
    $('.youtube-player').replaceWith($('<div class="youtube-player"><div class="youtube-player-video"><div class="youtube-player-object">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div></div></div>'));
    // start youtube-plugin
    $('.youtube-player').player(config);
}

// click handlers
$('#videoBtn1').click(function() {
    loadYouTube('3qQWibGlfb0', 'title 1 goes here');
});
$('#videoBtn2').click(function() {
    loadYouTube('b8MhLvjoBTs', 'title 2 goes here');
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CufJw/).

=== UPDATE ===

Put the event handler calls into an onclick-attribute of the buttons and remove them in the javascript:

```
<button type="button" id="videoBtn1" onclick="loadYouTube('3qQWibGlfb0', 'title 1 goes here');">video 1</button>
<button type="button" id="videoBtn2" onclick="loadYouTube('b8MhLvjoBTs', 'title 2 goes here');">video 2</button>
```

Also see [the updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/CufJw/2/).

=== UPDATE ===

Maybe this free ;-) example can help you:

html:

```
<div id="youtube-player">
    <div class="youtube-player-video">
        <div class="youtube-player-object">
            You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="videoBtn1" onclick="loadYouTube('3qQWibGlfb0', 'title 1 goes here');">video 1</button>
<button type="button" id="videoBtn2" onclick="loadYouTube('b8MhLvjoBTs', 'title 2 goes here');">video 2</button>
```

js:

```
var player = null;
var playlist = {
    title: 'Random videos',
    videos: []
};

function loadYouTube(id, title) {
    // check if player isn't already loaded
    if (typeof $('#youtube-player').data('jquery-youtube-player') == 'undefined') {
        // add video to playlist
        playlist.videos.push({id: id, title: title});
        // load player
        player = $('#youtube-player')
            .show()
            .player({
                repeatPlaylist: 1,
                showTime: 1,
                height: 356,
                toolbar: 'play,prev,next,shuffle,repeat,mute',
                playlist: playlist
            });
    }
    // if player is active
    else {
        var bFound = false;
        // search if video is already in playlist
        for (var i = 0; i < playlist.videos.length; i++) {
            if (playlist.videos[i].id == id) {
                bFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!bFound) {                       
            // add video to playlist
            playlist.videos.push({id: id, title: title});
            // load updated playlist
            player.player('loadPlaylist', playlist);
        }
        // show current video
        player.player('cueVideo', id);
    }
}
```

Also see this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CufJw/11/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I really appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for days and your code sample will help me a lot. Is it possible to move the handels outside of JS? and enter the youtube id and title using html?

Comment: Thanks! Have you used this plugin before?

Comment: I ran into a problem with the solution above. I would like it so when button #1 is pressed video #1 is added to the playlist. And if button #2 is pressed the video will be added to the playlist as well. Then the user will have the option to move back in forth between videos and use some of the other features of the plugin (shuffle, repeat). Similar to http://jsfiddle.net/d4DT2/2/ where you have multiple videos in the playlist and can switch to the next video, repeat, shuffle etc. Let me know if i am asking too much.

Comment: Kinda like a queue of videos added to the playlist to play.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out! I really appercated it! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some different approches here. But the main theme is that have each button use a identifier to tell the script what to do.

You could build a config object for each button:

> ```
>  var btn_config = { myBtn1: { youtubeId: 1, title: 'abc' }, myBtn2: { youtubeId: 2, title: 'abc' }}; 
> // And have each btn html element have the same id. And get the config like:
> $('a').click(function (e) {
>     var self = $(this),
>         currentConfig = btn_config[self.attr('id')];
>     // currentConfig.youtubeId
> });
> ```

You could also use html5 data attribute (these are pickup by jQuery):

```
// A html element with data-attribute
<a href="#" data-youtube-id="1" data-youtube-title="some title">Button</a>
// And to pick it up with jquery
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var self = $(this),
        youtubeId = self.data('youtubeId');
});
```

I would suggest the data-attribute way, since it gives some what simpler approch to adding new buttons.

Here's a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68csa/

..fredrik

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I go about inserting the ID and title in the jQuery code above? Sorry, I am really new at this.

Comment: If you look at my second suggestion you can add the id and title directly to the html elements.